# Plugin caused to crash Xcode

Tags: plugins, crash, xcode5

I've installed this plugin:

https://github.com/limejelly/Backlight-for-XCode

for highlighting the current editing line in Xcode, but unfortunately this plugin caused my Xcode 5.1 to crash every time I open it.

My question is how to remove this plugin ?

I've opened /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns
but I can't know how to remove this plugin ?

Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to ~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins
from Finder or press (command+shift+G)
Then delete these plugin :)

P.S: These plugin is working fine on Mavericks OS not mountain lion.